# ReactJS IE9 state not being refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-9

I have an application that, in IE9, does not seem to render properly on state change.  Pretty much it is just a product grid that when you click on an object, it should pop open a modal box with some product information and the ability to add the item to your shopping cart.  Right now, the grid renders, and when an object gets clicked only the modal overlay gets shown but the modal content is never loaded.  This works in all other browsers.  In addition, this works when IE9 dev console is open.

Here's pretty much how we are doing this:

```
var Modal = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
    modalOpen: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    onClose: React.PropTypes.func
  },
    render: function() {
    if (this.props.modalOpen) {
        return (
        <div>
          <div className="modal-overlay" onClick={this.props.onClose} />
          <div className="modal-content">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    else {
        return (<div />)
    }    
  }
});

var ProductModal = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
    modalOpen: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onClose: React.PropTypes.func
  },
    render: function() {
    return(
      <Modal modalOpen={this.props.modalOpen} onClose={this.props.onClose}>
        <div className="pdModal">
          This is where product details would go if we had them...
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
});

var ProductGrid = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
        return {
        modalIsOpen: false
      }
    },

    openModal: function() {
        this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: true
      });
    },

    closeModal: function() {
        this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: false
      });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div onClick={this.openModal}>CLICK ME TO OPEN THE MODAL</div>
            <ProductModal modalOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen} onClose={this.closeModal} />
          </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ProductGrid/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[Fiddle available here.](//jsfiddle.net/2fe1cttz/)  Yes I know the fiddle works on IE9, which is weirder because this is exactly how this is implemented on our site.  The only difference is that we are making an ajax request and waiting for results before rendering.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a caching issue?

Comment: Positive.  I've made sure to clear cache every time I reload.